# accessing the first value of the vector in dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe which consists of various variables and one particular column that has a vector in it. Is there some code to replace the value to the first vector that is found within the column?

| ID | Fees |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | c(420,700) |
| 2 | 400 |
| 3 | c(200,720) |

The desired Output:

| ID | Fees |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 420 |
| 2 | 400 |
| 3 | 200 |

Comment: `df$Fees <- sapply(df$Fees, "[[", 1)`

Comment: @onyambu Post as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could loop through the vector using `sapply` and extracting the first value:

```
df$Fees <- sapply(df$Fees, "[[", 1)
```

Comment: This is the most parsimonious solution, I like it.

Comment: @onyambu if now I want to extract the last value instead, how can I edit your code to get the last value?

Comment: @JordanIatro YOU will use a different code since the position of the last value is not fixed. Use `sapply(df$Fees, tail, 1)` and for the 1rst value, instead of the above code that i gave, you can use `sapply(df$Fees, head, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using `map` and `pluck` to pull out the first item in the vectors:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(Fees =  map_dbl(Fees, pluck, 1))
```

**Output**

```
  ID Fees
1  1  420
2  2  400
3  3  200
```

Or another option using `rowwise` and an index:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(Fees = Fees[1])
```

We could also use `pluck` with `rowwise`:

```
df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(Fees = pluck(Fees, 1))
```

Or we could just skip the use of `purrr` and use `first` with `rowwise`:

```
df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(Fees = first(Fees))
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, Fees = list(c(420, 700), 400, c(200, 
720))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The first code should be `df %>% mutate(Fees =  map_dbl(Fees, pluck, 1))`; otherwise, the output is still a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map_dbl()` from `purrr` to extract the *n-th* element of each element in a list.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(Fee1 = map_dbl(Fees, 1))

# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#      ID Fees       Fee1
#   <int> <list>    <dbl>
# 1     1 <dbl [2]>   420
# 2     2 <dbl [1]>   400
# 3     3 <dbl [2]>   200
```

---

###### Data

```r
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, Fees = list(c(420, 700), 400, c(200, 720))),
row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

We could do it this way:

The bottle neck is that `Fees` is `list`. With `paste` we make it `character`.
Then we use `parse_number`. This extracts always only the first number:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Fees = parse_number(paste(Fees)))
```

```
  ID Fees
1  1  420
2  2  400
3  3  200
```

Comment: Why would you parse a number from a vector?this will totally fail

Comment: The idea behind is that `parse_number` accesses always the first number of a vector?! And I think this is the question here?! The problem is that `Fees` is a list. with `paste` we transform it to character to be able to use my favorite function `parse_number`. Note this was added after all other relevant solution were already provided and upvoted by me!

Comment: I did not see the `paste` part. I just saw the parse_number and was wondering as to why you would do that. Will upvote now that i see the logic